Non-blocking loop inside an inkscape extension
Is it possible to have a non-blocking loop constantly running from within an Inkscape extension?
I would like - for example - to be able to pass information back and forth to another application every time I update the drawing.
I have tried threads and forking, but neither releases control to Inkscape for as long as the extension is running.

Could you add an example of the threads you have used? Have you consider using  signals?

@LucasM.Uriarte - yes, later in the day, and no, could you point me to something to understand signals as the topic
